# Issues with a MySQL Index due to a specific part

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

The query is

```
SELECT row 
  FROM `table`
   USE INDEX(`indexName`)
 WHERE row1 = '0'
   AND row2 = '0' 
   AND row3 >= row4 
   AND (row5 = '0' OR row5 LIKE 'value')
```

I have the following MySQL Query which I've created a index for using;

```
CREATE INDEX indexName ON `table` (row1, row2, row3, row5);
```

However, the performance is not really good. It's extracting about 17,000+ rows out of a 5.9+ million row table in anywhere from 6-12 seconds.

It seems like the bottleneck is the `row3` >= `row4` - because without that part in the code it runs in 0.6-0.7 seconds.

(from Comment)

The row (placeholder column name) is actually the id (primary key, index) column in the table, which is the result set I'm outputting later on. I'm outputting an array of IDs that are matching the parameters in my query, and then selecting a random ID from that array to gather data through the final query on a specific row. This was done as a workaround for rand(). Any adjustments needed based on that knowledge?

Comment: Start with EXPLAIN ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: I think you're confused about rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

17K rows is not a tiny result set. Large result sets often take time just because of the overhead of delivering the data from the MySQL server to the program requesting them.

The contents of the `'value'` you use in `row5 LIKE 'value'` matter a great deal to query performance. If `'value'` starts with a wildcard character like `%` your query will be slow.

That being said, you need a so-called [covering index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index).  You've tried to create one with the index you created. It's close but not perfect.

Your query filters on equality to constant values on `row1`, `row2`, and `row5`, so those columns should come first in your index. The query planner can random-access your index to the first matching entry, and then sequentially scan the index until it gets to the last matching entry.  That's as fast as it gets.

Then you want to examine `row3` and `row4` (to compare them). Those columns should come next in the index. Finally, if your query's `SELECT` clause mentions a subset of the columns in your `table` you should put the rest of those columns in the index.  So, based on the query in your question, your index should be

```
 CREATE INDEX indexName ON `table` (row1, row2, row5, row3, row4, row);
```

The query planner will be able to satisfy the entire query by scanning through a subset of the index, using a so-called index range scan. That should be decently fast.

Pro tip: don't force the query planner's hand with `USE INDEX()`. Instead, structure your indexes to handle your queries efficiently.

Comment: The `row` (placeholder column name) is actually the `id` (primary key, index) column in the table, which is the result set I'm outputting later on. I'm outputting an array of IDs that are matching the parameters in my query, and then selecting a random ID from that array to gather data through the final query on a specific row. This was done as a workaround for rand().

Any adjustments needed based on that knowledge?

Comment: Just to notify you. Your index made it go from 9 seconds or so to around 2 :-) @O. Jones

Answer (score 0):

An index can't be used to compare two columns in the same table (at best, it could be used for an index scan rather than a table scan if all output fields are contained in the index), so there basically is no "correct" way to do this.

If you have control over the structure AND the processes the fill the table, you could add a calculated field that holds the difference between the two fields. Then add that field to the index and adjust your query to use that field instead of the other 2.

It ain't pretty and doesn't offer a lot of flexibility (eg. if you want to compare another field, you need to add it as well etc), but it does get the job done.

Comment: Not sure how I would make that work, as I need to ensure that `row3` is always bigger or equal to `row4`. Plotting the number between those two wouldn't allow for any comparison as far as I can think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, suppose you call the calculated field row6 and set it to the value of row3 - row4. If the value of row6 is bigger or equal than 0, row3 is bigger or equal to row4. If the value is smaller than 0, row4 is bigger than row3.  You can then add row6 to the index so that it can be searched efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an adaptation of http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random )

Let's actually fold the randomization into the query.  This will eliminate gathering a bunch of ids, processing them, and then reaching back into the table.  It will also avoid the need for an extra index.

1. Find min and max `id` values.
2. Pick a random `id` between min and max.
3. Scan forward, looking for the first row with col1...col5 matching the criteria.

Something like...

```
SELECT b.*   -- should replace with actual list of columns
    FROM
        ( SELECT id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE id >= ( SELECT MIN(id) +
                                 ( MAX(id) - MIN(id)
                                   - 22   -- somewhat avoids running off end
                                 ) * RAND()
                              FROM tbl )
              AND col1 = 0 ...  -- your various criteria
            ORDER BY id
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b  USING(id);
```

Pros/cons:

- Probably faster than anything else you can devise.
- If there `RAND()` hits too late in the table, it will return nothing.  In this (rare) case, run the query again, but starting at 0.
- Big gaps in `id` will lead to a bias in which `id` is returned.  (The link above discusses some kludges to handle such.)

Comment: The table has 5.9 million rows and 17,000 are extracted at the moment. Some could be ID 200 and some could be ID 5,900,382 - wouldn't that be a problem? @Rick

Comment: @Patrick - Yes, you have brought up a problem.  If, for example, id=3,123,456 is the last id that matches `col1=0 AND ...`, then it will scan a long time (2M rows) without finding anything.  All the alternatives so far involve scanning however many rows have `col1=0 AND col2=0` (_no further_`).  How many such rows?